# How do I make my star rotate? I am able to make the star but do not know how to make it rotate

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

This is the code I have to draw the star

```
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0f));
        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        
        g2d.drawLine(-40, -90, 40, 40);
        g2d.drawLine(80, -90, 40, 40);
        g2d.drawLine(80, -90, -80, 0);
        g2d.drawLine(-80, 0, 160, 0);
        g2d.drawLine(160, 0, -40, -90);
```

Comment: You should use the Swing tag rather than jframe and jpanel. You should also read the eclipse tag and remove it, because nothing you're doing is specific to eclipse. Also, please put in a [mre] rather than just a simple code-snippet. I'm making these suggestions to help you prevent this from being closed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.  Another would be to build the star in a `Polygon` class and either rotate the Polygon itself or rotate the graphics context. Note that I *winged* the star creation by trial and error.  The one point of the star was calculated using trigonometry and then rotated to draw all five points.

Also, note that I built the star in the `paintComponent` method.  Probably not the best thing to do as it is important to keep processing in the Event Dispatch Thread to a minimum.

The rate rotation is controlled by both the angle increment and the timer delay.  And in this case the timer is a Swing timer.

If you want to see your version of the star rotate, just comment out my `drawStar` method call and and uncomment your code within `paintComponent`

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class StarPicture {
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new StarPicture().start());
    }
    
    public void start() {
        Timer t = new Timer(0, (ae)-> frame.repaint());
        t.setDelay(50);  //50 milliseconds per rotational increment
        t.start();
    }
    
    public StarPicture() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        // center on screen
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    double angle = 0;
    static double RADIUS = 50;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        // visually smooth the lines
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f));
        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        // set the origin to the center of the panel
        g2d.translate(250,250);
        g2d.rotate(angle);
        // draw the star in the center of the panel
        drawStar(g2d);      
    
//      g2d.drawLine(-40, -90, 40, 40);
//      g2d.drawLine(80, -90, 40, 40);
//      g2d.drawLine(80, -90, -80, 0);
//      g2d.drawLine(-80, 0, 160, 0);
//      g2d.drawLine(160, 0, -40, -90);
            
// adjust the amount of rotation per timer interval
        angle += Math.PI/200;
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    public static void drawStar(Graphics2D g) {
        int a = (int)(RADIUS*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(54)));
        int b = (int)(RADIUS*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(54)));
        int y = (int)(a*Math.tan(Math.toRadians(72)))+b;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            g.drawLine(-a,b,0,y);
            g.drawLine(a,b,0,y);
            g.rotate(Math.toRadians(72));
        }
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500,500);
    }
}
```

I suggest you read more about all the methods in the Graphics2D classes, and AffineTransform classes to understand what all you can do.  Also, check out the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) to learn more about painting.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a field angle, to draw with that angle:

```
double angle;

    g2d.rotate(angle, 60, 65);
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0f));
    g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);        
    g2d.drawLine(-40, -90, 40, 40);
    g2d.drawLine(80, -90, 40, 40);
    g2d.drawLine(80, -90, -80, 0);
    g2d.drawLine(-80, 0, 160, 0);
    g2d.drawLine(160, 0, -40, -90);
    g2d.rotate(-angle, 60, 65); // Undo rotation for other paints.
```

The rotation happens around the center (60, 65 if I have counted correctly)

For an animated continuous rotation one can use a swing Timer:

```
ActionListener tickTack = evt -> {
    angle += Math.PI / 8;
    if (angle >= 2 * Math.PI) {
        angle -= 2 * Math.PI;
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer(1000L, tickTack, this); // Start after 1000 ms.
timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.setDelay(100L); // Every 100 ms.
timer.start();
```