# How to rotate something with Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

So I want to rotate this Rectangle I made

```
public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.fillRect(10, 10, 30, 30);
        g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(45)); //I tried this but doesn't seem to work... 
    }
```

How do I do that? Rotate as in rotate in 45* angle or 200* angle.

Comment: Use an [`AffineTransform`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html).

Comment: A better way is to store your rectangle as a logical rectangle (using an instance of java.awt.Rectangle), using polar coordinates to calculate the rotated rectangle end-points, and converting those polar coordinate end-points back to cartesian coordinates to actually draw the rectangle.

Comment: Calling rotate rotates the graphics context, not the actual object.  You should be using the version of rotate that translates the origin so that the graphics context is rotated about the center of your rectangle. Check out the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66106823/how-do-i-make-my-star-rotate-i-am-able-to-make-the-star-but-do-not-know-how-to/66108980#66108980).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really isn't that hard to rotate objects.  Most of the code below is simply boiler plate to create the frames and panels. Here is a demo that shows two methods that were mentioned in the comments.

- the left panel simply rotates the graphics context.  This is, imo, the easiest method but it does not alter the object.
- the right panel uses the `AffineTransform` to rotate the object. This actually changes the contents of the shape.

If the desire is to rotate an object in place it is necessary to ensure one is rotating about the middle of the image that is under rotation.  In both cases below that would be `(125,125)` or the center of both the panels and the rectangle.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class RotateRectangle extends JPanel {
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    double angle = 0;
    MyPanel mypanel = new MyPanel();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities
                .invokeLater(() -> new RotateRectangle().start());
    }
    
    public void start() {
        Timer t = new Timer(0, (ae) -> {mypanel.rotateit(); frame.repaint();});
        t.setDelay(30);
        t.start();
    }
    
    public RotateRectangle() {
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.add(mypanel);
        setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red,2));
        mypanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 2));
        frame.pack();
        // center on screen
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        
        // visually smooth the lines
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        
        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.rotate(angle, 125,125);
        g2d.drawRect(75, 75, 100, 100);
        
// adjust the amount of rotation per timer interval
        angle += Math.PI / 200;
        g2d.dispose();
    }
    
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(250, 250);
    }
    
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    // amount to rotate
    double angle = Math.PI / 200;
    Shape shape = polygon;
    AffineTransform af =  new AffineTransform();

    public MyPanel() {
        af.rotate(angle, 125,125);
        polygon.addPoint(75,175);
        polygon.addPoint(175,175);
        polygon.addPoint(175,75);
        polygon.addPoint(75,75);

    }
    public void rotateit() {
        
        shape = af.createTransformedShape(shape);
    
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (shape == null) {
            return;
        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        
        // visually smooth the lines
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        
        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.draw(shape);
        
    }
    
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(250, 250);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following up on my comment, I created the following GUI.

[image: Rotating Rectangle]

I used math to calculate the four endpoints of a rotated rectangle and used the `Graphics2D` `fillPolygon` method to draw the rectangle.

The buttons at the bottom of the GUI allow you to rotate the rectangle on the center point or the upper left endpoint.

I created a drawing `JPanel` to draw the rectangle.  All the `paintComponent` method of the drawing `JPanel` does is draw the `Polygon` returned by the application model.

The application model is a key part of this application.  I create a plain Java getter / setter class.  I start with a `java.awt.Rectangle` and use polar coordinates to rotate the rectangle.  I convert the polar coordinates back to cartesian coordinates to get the four endpoints of the `Polygon`.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class RotatingRectangle implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RotatingRectangle());
    }
    
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    private JButton centerButton;
    private JButton endPointButton;
    
    private RotatedRectangle rotatedRectangle;
    
    public RotatingRectangle() {
        this.rotatedRectangle = new RotatedRectangle(Color.BLUE, 
                new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 50));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rotating Rectangle");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(rotatedRectangle);
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
        
        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener(this, rotatedRectangle);
        
        centerButton = new JButton("Rotate on center point");
        centerButton.addActionListener(listener);
        panel.add(centerButton);
        
        endPointButton = new JButton("Rotate on end point");
        endPointButton.addActionListener(listener);
        endPointButton.setPreferredSize(centerButton.getPreferredSize());
        panel.add(endPointButton);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }
    
    public JButton getCenterButton() {
        return centerButton;
    }

    public JButton getEndPointButton() {
        return endPointButton;
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private RotatedRectangle rotatedRectangle;
        
        public DrawingPanel(RotatedRectangle rotatedRectangle) {
            this.rotatedRectangle = rotatedRectangle;
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            Polygon polygon = rotatedRectangle.getRectangle();
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setColor(rotatedRectangle.getColor());
            g2d.fillPolygon(polygon);
        }
        
    }
    
    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        
        private final RotatingRectangle frame;
        
        private final RotatedRectangle model;
        
        private Timer timer;

        public ButtonListener(RotatingRectangle frame, RotatedRectangle model) {
            this.frame = frame;
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.stop();
            }
            
            JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();
            if (button.equals(frame.getEndPointButton())) {
                model.setCenterPoint(false);
                model.setAngle(180);
            } else {
                model.setCenterPoint(true);
                model.setAngle(0);
            }
            
            timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    model.incrementAngle(1);
                    frame.repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }
        
        
    }

    public class RotatedRectangle {
        
        private boolean centerPoint;
        
        private int angle;
        
        private final Color color;
        
        private final Rectangle rectangle;

        public RotatedRectangle(Color color, Rectangle rectangle) {
            this.color = color;
            this.rectangle = rectangle;
            this.angle = 0;
            this.centerPoint = true;
        }

        public int getAngle() {
            return angle;
        }

        public void setAngle(int angle) {
            this.angle = angle;
        }
        
        public void incrementAngle(int increment) {
            this.angle += increment;
            this.angle %= 360; 
        }

        public Polygon getRectangle() {
            Point rotatePoint = new Point(rectangle.x, rectangle.y);
            if (isCenterPoint()) {
                int x = rectangle.x + rectangle.width / 2;
                int y = rectangle.y + rectangle.height / 2;
                rotatePoint = new Point(x, y);
            }
            
            Point[] point = new Point[4];
            int width = rectangle.x + rectangle.width;
            int height = rectangle.y + rectangle.height;
            point[0] = new Point(rectangle.x, rectangle.y);
            point[1] = new Point(width, rectangle.y);
            point[2] = new Point(width, height);
            point[3] = new Point(rectangle.x, height);
            
            Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
            for (int i = 0; i < point.length; i++) {
                point[i] = calculatePoint(rotatePoint, point[i], angle);
                polygon.addPoint(point[i].x, point[i].y);
            }
            
            return polygon;
        }
        
        private Point calculatePoint(Point rotatePoint, Point point, int angle) {
            double theta = Math.toRadians(angle);
            int xDistance = rotatePoint.x - point.x;
            int yDistance = rotatePoint.y - point.y;
            double distance = Math.sqrt(xDistance * xDistance + yDistance * yDistance);
            double alpha = Math.atan2(yDistance, xDistance);
            
            theta += alpha;
            int x = (int) Math.round(Math.cos(theta) * distance) + rotatePoint.x;
            int y = (int) Math.round(Math.sin(theta) * distance) + rotatePoint.y;
            
            return new Point(x, y);
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public boolean isCenterPoint() {
            return centerPoint;
        }

        public void setCenterPoint(boolean centerPoint) {
            this.centerPoint = centerPoint;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```